# Flexbox grid layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a grid layout for some details. I figured I'd use flexbox since I've been using it for most the page. I'm using flex direction column. Here's what I have so far.

Practitioner Pricing: $80

Early Registration:$80

Regular Price:$80

Student Pricing: $80

Early Registration:

Regular Price:

**\\But what I want is...//**

Practitioner Pricing:

Early Registration:$80

Regular Price: $80

Student Pricing:

Early Registration: $80

Regular Price: $80

What I tried doing was adding "filler cells" for the rows in the column that need not be filled.But this isn't the correct approach so far.

```
                <div class="sdp-pricing-label">
                    <div><p style="font-weight:bold">Practitioner Pricing:</p></div>
                    <div><p>Early Registration:</p></div>
                    <div><p>Regular Price:</p></div>
                    <div><p style="font-weight:bold">Student Pricing:</p></div>
                    <div><p>Early Registration:</p></div>
                    <div><p>Regular Price:</p></div>
                </div>
                <div class="sdp-pricing-amount">
                    <div class="sdp-pricing-cell-spacer"><p></p></div>
                    <div><p>$89.00</p></div>
                    <div><p>$129.00</p></div>
                    <div class="sdp-pricing-cell-spacer"><p></p></div>
                    <div><p>$50.00</p></div>
                    <div><p>$75.00</p></div>
                </div>
```

here is the scss

```
  .sdp-pricing-label{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
  }

  .sdp-pricing-amount{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;

    .sdp-pricing-cell-spacer{
      p{width:100%;}
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using flex:1 in the spacer cells works perfect

Answer (score 0):

SO the issue is that while you are setting up individual flexbox columns you have to wrap them in a flex box wrapper that dictates how those columns interact as rows.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xerbhvap/) of your code. To change where the text sits within each individual box just change justification or alignment on that text.

```
   <div><p style="font-weight:bold">Practitioner Pricing:</p></div>
  <div class="wrapper">

              <div class="sdp-pricing-label">
                    <div><p>Early Registration:</p></div>
                    <div><p>Regular Price:</p></div>
                    <div><p style="font-weight:bold">Student Pricing:</p></div>
                    <div><p>Early Registration:</p></div>
                    <div><p>Regular Price:</p></div>
                </div>
                <div class="sdp-pricing-amount">
                    <div class="sdp-pricing-cell-spacer"><p></p></div>
                    <div><p>$89.00</p></div>
                    <div><p>$129.00</p></div>
                    <div class="sdp-pricing-cell-spacer"><p></p></div>
                    <div><p>$50.00</p></div>
                    <div><p>$75.00</p></div>
                </div>
                </div>
```